# How can I make my fixed position article slider smooth on the iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, css, slider

My client needs an article scroller that leaves the outgoing article at it's current scroll position and brings on the new one in at the top.

I have achieved this using CSS3 transitions by setting the top margin of the outgoing article to a negative value equal to the current $(window).scrollTop() value and then scrolling the page to the top using $(window).scrollTop(0).  Once the slide is complete I reset the outgoing article's top margin to zero, ready for the next transition.  I have uploaded a simplified example here http://www.siblify.com/stackslider/ but here is the code that specifically manages the 'next' click scroll.

```
#container {
height:auto;
width:800px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0 auto;
padding:60px 0 20px;
}

.slidePanel {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:760px;
z-index:900;
background:grey;
-webkit-transition:left .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:left .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:left .5s ease-in-out;
padding:60px 20px 20px;
}

.prevPanel {
left:-800px;
}

.currentPanel {
z-index:1000;
display:block;
}

.nextPanel {
left:800px;
}

div.sliding {
left:0;
}

div.slidingOffLeft {
left:-840px;
}

div.slidingOffRight {
left:840px;
}

<div id="controls">
        <a href="prev">Prev</a> <a href="next">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="prevPanel slidePanel">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>

        <div class="currentPanel slidePanel">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>

        <div class="nextPanel slidePanel">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>
    </div>

$('a[href="next"]').click(function(i) {
        i.preventDefault();
        $('.prevPanel').remove();
        $('.currentPanel').css({
            "margin-top": "-" + $(window).scrollTop() + "px"
        });
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        $('.currentPanel').addClass('slidingOffLeft').delay(500).removeClass('slidingOffLeft currentPanel').addClass('prevPanel');
        $('.nextPanel').addClass('sliding').delay(500).removeClass('sliding nextPanel').addClass('currentPanel');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#container').height($('.currentPanel').height());
            $('.prevPanel').css({
                'margin-top': '0px'
            });
        }, 500)

        })
```

This method works perfectly on desktop browsers but on the iPad the addition of a negative margin and $(window).scrollTop(0) does not happen instantly so you see a slight blip as the window scrolls to the top before the article is pulled back up into position.

Any advice as to how I could get these two events to fire simultaneously on iOS or an alternative approach that would improve performance would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** On my example the 'prev' and 'next' buttons jump down the page on click.  This is a known iOS fixed positioning bug which is not an issue for me on this project as the final version will be gesture controlled.

Comment: What about scrolling only the panel with text..Not whole window.That way you will be able to only change the margin and next panel will automaticaly in its default position (scrolled to top)

Comment: Thanks for the idea simekadam, it kind of worked for me.  I still need the page to scroll normally for desktops so I have targeted the iPad screen size and just scrolled the panel for them.  The only issue that this has raised is that by making the panel scrollable it disables elastic scrolling which doesn't look so great.  I can re-enable it using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; but then the page transitions become really slow and jerky.  So not perfect but hopefully acceptable for now.

Comment: actually now I am sittin here with an iPad, I will test it a then maybe reply some further idea how to solve ir

Answer (score 0):

Whoa..So I have looke on your code and got quite confused..It looks quite complicated:D
You have there lots of classes toggling on and of..
How I would solve this thing somehow like this..(warning I am tired so I will be using some kind of pseudocode:))

```
DIV 1 with overflow hidden and fixed bounds
 DIV 2 which will be as wide as sum of widths of all panels
  PANEL 1 fixed width height and so on..
  PANEL 2
  .....
  PANEL N
 2 VID :)
1 VID
```

Then you can apply CSS TRANSFORM to the `DIV 2` like this

```
CSS:
DIV 2
  -webkit-transntion:  left 500ms;
  // in case you will be faced with flickering while the transition going on try using this - should help
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Then you can have something like this in your JS

```
 onTouchForwardButton
     offset = DIV_2.left - currPanel.next().width()
     DIV_2.css(left, offset);
```

Again..When you wont be scrolling whole body you can avoid the scrollTop function..Or you can postpone it to the transtion callback..You can handle it with `webkitTransitionEnd` event. BUt I think scrolling only every panel element makes way more sense in this situation. So after all try to do it this way and it maybe will be behaving better even with the scrollTop function..I think in your code could be problem with those delays and timeouts..

So again sorry for this nasty pseudocode, but I am lazy to write brackets and so on..Maybe tomorrow I can make this better and rewrite my answer..

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look at this.  I'll have a go at implementing what you suggested and report back.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering - I ended up using 3d transforms for this in the end.  It utilizes ipad hardware acceleration and created a properly smooth transition.